# How do I limit randomness in KOTH challenge?

Tags: discussion

I'm always fan of game theory game with chance. However, one of the downsides is, that when one agent plays random, it's basically become mixed strategy, and meh....

One interesting case is my [penalty shooter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37694/penalty-shootout). When I designed this game, what comes into my mind is that this will be something like [RPSSV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35079/the-rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-tournament-of-epicness) just with more variable.

When we discuss this game on sandbox, nobody really taught about this game being abused by randomness. What we're talking about that this game is boring because it's zero sum game.

Then when it's launched... a bot with pure randomness comes in less then a minute. I tried to bend the rule, but I can't find the right word to "forbid" randomness.

The trouble is, too much randomness is mixed strategy, too few randomness is too deterministic, and starts the trend of "this entry is specifically to kill other entry"

What will be the right wording, to "forbid" randomness, without killing the game spirit.

Comment: @Geobits Have you saw the entry? =p

Comment: It pretty much kill the spirit of the game(subjective). In the RPSSV, even people can get creative with randomness. In penalty shooter, it just bang!

Comment: That's the point of the question. I know overkill is vague, I don't know how to make it not vague.

Comment: So the only option is binary yes/no?

Comment: You two should [bring this to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), and then come back and post your results. 9 comments in 9 minutes is kind of a lot.

Comment: Random play is just part of the strategy landscape, there is nothing wrong with it and no need to limit it. If the challenge is no fun in the presence of random entries then the *challenge needs work*.

Comment: If by "*nobody taught that*" you mean "*nobody thought that*" then you missed the point of my first comment on your sandbox post.

Answer (score 1):

So, after some intense discussion, we receive some agreement.

## [Mind your audience](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18306732#18306732)

It turns out that the reason of Penalty Shooter doesn't work is because soccer is not famous in US. While RPS is. Even though RPS is also game where randomness is really best strategy, it works because it is a hit. So message to other game developer, you want to suit your game for your audience in US. What hits in the world, sometimes doesn't really hits in US (where most user come from)

## [If you want random() to die, penalty them as part of game mechanic](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18306727#18306727)

In the game [Good Versus Evil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33137/good-versus-evil), the game rewards consistency, which randomness is bad at.

Community wiki as you see. Go ahead and add what you see fit.